# Information Theoretic Oblivious Transfer?

Tags: multiparty-computation, protocol-analysis, oblivious-transfer

Do we have information theoretic oblivious transfer protocols that are that can not be broken by a computationally unbounded attacker?

Comment: An Oblivious Transfer Protocol that can not be broken by a computationally unbounded attacker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible to achieve (fully) information theoretic oblivious transfer (OT), since OT is complete (and so can compute all functions). Since many (most) functions cannot be securely computed information theoretically with two parties, this means that it's impossible. Having said that, we do have OT protocols that provide information-theoretic security for a corrupted sender and computational security for a corrupted receiver, and other OT protocols that provide information-theoretic security for a corrupted receiver and computational security for a corrupted sender.

Comment: Thanks! Could you answer this please - https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/75212/why-is-this-functionality-chosen-for-uc-nizk?

Comment: Occasionally one will see papers that highlight the fact that OT can be obtained from different kinds of noisy channels. In light of that, it might make sense to consider "OT from physical assumptions" as a form of information-theoretic or unconditional OT.

Comment: Are there resources available where I can learn more about these IT/computationally secure OT protocols?

Comment: I am correct that you meant: It is impossible to achieve (fully) information theoretic **two-party** oblivious transfer (OT)?